# How many of their caches do chickadees retrieve?

Tags: ornithology, ethology, memory

Chickadees are scatter-caching birds and I've heard they can hide as many as 10,000 seeds for retrieval over the winter. How many of these cached seeds actually end up getting used in a typical winter? And can the chickadee really remember all of the locations?

Comment: I'd guess about the same percentage as squirrels and their acorns, and yes, they remember where every one is hidden, but they have a hell of a time finding their car keys.